# Excel automation with python

Tags: python, excel, automation

I have been working with excel vba for some period of time related with automation. Now I am planning to upgrade to python. I did a little bit of research on how to implement automation using python. All I see people doing coding with PyCharm or Jupiter, to do an automation user has to have knowledge of python. What I want to know is how to create a tool or standalone application with python that does a repetitive task, calculation or report generation in  excel. Where the end user doesn't have to worry about python or codes or learning new technology to accomplish the task.

Comment: Make a Tkinter GUI to perform the operations you desire. You could refer this https://medium.com/@medasuryatej/working-with-excel-and-python-xlwt-92badd3116dd  or the automate the boring stuff with python

Comment: If you are looking for some Excel plugins type thing, you might try https://www.xlwings.org/ -- For a true standalone, I really like PyQt5 for my native desktop apps (I.E. not within Excel, but modifying .xlsx files)

Answer (score 2):

I know this isn't technically and answer, and since I can't comment yet (too low rep), I'm going to point you to [automate the boring stuff with python](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/).  I'm sure you can find your answer here plus some!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer.

https://github.com/TaeYoon2/ExcelAutomation

This project is a sample excel automation program with python.

I used 'openpyxl' library.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to stackoverflow. Here are a few resources that hopefully get you started on your journey to automating excel tasks with python then wrapping your project up for non-python users.

### Python libraries that interface with excel (these are for you to write your excel automation projects)

- openpyxl [docs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html)
- pandas [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html)
- pylightxl [docs](https://pylightxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html)
- more at http://www.python-excel.org/

### Wrapping up your project for non-programmers

There are a few options here for your non-programmer users.

1. Have users run your python project on command line where you give them prompts to respond to for your automation (ie. input excel file name, automation task inputs etc). This is probably the simplest task on your end, but it does expect your users to know how to user command line.
2. Have users run your python project on command line but you create a graphical user interface (GUI) for them to ease the input field options. This requires some up front work on your end to wrap you input with a GUI of your choice; here are a few [tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#module-tkinter), [pyqt](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/).

Note that both of these options require your users to have python on their machine with the proper packages ready to go to execute your project. This can be a lot to ask for non-python users. Therefore finally you could use a packaging software like [pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html) to wrap up your python project into an .exe

Hope that helps! Happy pythoning